# RuntimeWarning in scipy.optimize.minimize when trying to MLE fit Weibull distribution

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, statistics

I have the following function `to_minimize` which should be equal to the log-likelihood of a dataset for a Weibull distribution, truncated from the left at d.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def to_minimize(args, data, d=1):
  theta, tau = args
  n = len(data)
  if tau <= 0 or theta <= 0:
    pass
  term1 = n * (np.log(tau) - tau * np.log(theta) - (-d / theta) ** tau)
  term2 = 0
  for x in data:
    term2 += (tau - 1) * np.log(x) + (-x / theta) ** tau
  return term1 + term2

data = numpy.random.rand(100)
weibull = minimize(lambda args: -to_minimize(args, data),
                   x0=np.array((1., 1.)), bounds=np.array([(1e-15, 10), (1e-15, 10)]))
```

As far as I can tell, the only thing that should cause an error of the form

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
```

should be if tau or theta are 0. But the bounds on those parameters is specifically above 0 so why does my optimization routine crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling `np.seterr(all='raise')` and debugging some more, I noticed that I had an error in my calculations. The `-` in the exponential function has to be applied after the power. Otherwise it will try to take the root of a negative number which won't work for obvious reasons.